# Countdown timer for a key on custom keyboard

Tags: android, android-studio

I would like to add a countdown timer for a key for 5 minutes. 
either a countdown should see on key or turn on a caps light for 5 minutes after key press. 
Anyway to implement this on custom keyboard? 
I used a eclipse tutorial and made my changes to that. But i don't know how to add this function on a key
my switch case for that particular key is,

```
case 905:
            String chop = "DiscordRPG chop";
            ic.commitText(chop, 1);
            ic.sendKeyEvent(kd); ic.sendKeyEvent(ku);
            break;
```

Comment: So, you want to start a countdown on a custom keyboard key press for five minutes? Do you want to disable keys for this period or it's just a countdown

Comment: No. I don't want to disable the keys for now. But I would like to know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider a key has code 1050 and when it pressed, you want to start a countdown. During this, you want to disable other keys and show the countdown on a key or may be in a `Toast`

```
case 1050:

 //To disable keys while countdown, move below 2 lines code to the first line of onKey()

if(isCountDownRunning)
  return;

 isCountDownRunning = true;
 new CountDownTimer(5 * 60 * 1000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
     //here, update the key label or a toast.

     //update label of key 20
     keyboard.getKeys().get(20).label = millisUnitFinished / ( 60 * 1000);

    //or, show a toast
    //Toast.make(this, "Remaining time : " + millisUnitFinished / ( 60 * 1000), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

 }

 public void onFinish() {
     isCountDownRunning = false;
 }
}.start();
```

Now, inside `onKey()` first check if `isCountDownRunning` is `true` then `return null` otherwise execute the rest of the method.

Comment: any new libraries to import

Comment: No lib is needed. Just import `android.os.CountDownTimer ` for countdownTimer

Comment: is the entire code is in that switch statement new case 1050.

Comment: Yes, it's in a `switch` statement of `keycode`. Past the above code in the  `case` of key/keycode you want to start countdown

Comment: Make sure you have keys in xml with `code` 1050 and 666 as per your code snippet. Also, create the variable `isCountDownRunning`

Comment: variable? i made `boolean isCountDownRunning = true`

Comment: nope. trying to make a keyboard for text based game in discord. (They banned boting, So I needed to find a easy way to type those commands)

Comment: hmm :) .. remove the error   `keyboard.getKeys().get(20).label = millisUnitFinished / ( 60 * 1000) + "";`  Also, create the variable outside of `onKey()`  method

Comment: A BUG: https://hastebin.com/exotipowuy.sql    Do i need to incrase the size of timer showing key(666)

Comment: You have only 12 keys and you are accessing key 666, which you don't have, this is why the exception is thrown.  replace 666 with 10

Comment: No timer or nothing happens. Working like previously.

Comment: keyboard looks like: https://i.imgur.com/83UhwaN.jpg I want it so that when pressed `chop button` a countdown timer will shows on that key label. this 5 minutes also want to be for other keys `forage, fish, mine` too. So may be need to make it public, so just need to call it to other keys as well.

Comment: o, `Toast` unknown entity

Comment: After they `keyboard.getKe()....` line add `mKeyboardView.setKeyboard(keyboard)` the timer will start display on key

Comment: for `Toast`, i need to skipp that `keyboard.getKey()........` line right.

Comment: No, it's not necessary. Just import Toast class

Comment: the time shows in minutes.. Is it possible to make that in seconds. Also in `Toast.make` error, `Toast.makeText`  gives error too

Comment: For seconds use this code `keyboard.getKeys().get(20).label = millisUnitFinished / ( 1000) + "";` and I guess toast is not showing becuase it's not on UI thread so replace it with this ` runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
           //todo add your Toast here
        }
    });`

Comment: it counts the time again when I tap it

Comment: like running more than 1 timer on that key. 

Comment: possible to disable that key till timer ends. 

Comment: also, keyboard label stays on 1.. need to make the label as on the keyboard xml file after timer ends.

Comment: Actually, I can't solve your whole set of problems. I think you need a service for it, maybe on Fiverr.

Comment: Can you just tell me how to stop repeating countdown timer. I don't want to disable keys.

Comment: Just how to stop the timer repeating before current one ends.

Comment: I made the timer for 5 keys. Problem is I can't use popup keys while timer running. as it's updates entire keyboard. I did add `invalidateAllKeys` to return to old one after timer ends

Comment: Anyway it was very helpful. Thank you very much friend.